# mysql 5.6 installion and configuration on windows

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i have installed MySQL server with developer default, I can connect to database with local application, How ever i am not able to connect to database from other system on the network it saying unable to reach database. I access database with root user and password

please give me steps to configure my MySQL server so that i can access database from any system in my network

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a user allowing him to connect from any host (`'user'@'%'`) and use that user to connect to your MySQL server machine. Also, you'll have to set `bind-address` of your MySQL configuration to your server machine's IP.

Check the following article. Although it is for Linux environment, you can get the general idea of what is to be done.

https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/mysql/remote-access/